# Is this a secure implementation of JWT refresh tokens?

Tags: authentication, jwt, token

I am implementing a JWT refresh token and have developed the following way of refreshing tokens. The following is the program flow:

- When server retrieves login information, it checks against password
  database and creates JWT token with a refresh token as one of its
  claims in the payload. (random characters). It will store the refresh
  token in a database.
- Upon login, server returned login:true and the JWT access token
- Since the refresh token is inside the JWT, two tokens do not need to
  be sent
- If the client sends an access token that has expired, the server will
  check the refresh token in the claims and see if it is inside the db.
  If it is, it will generate a new token with a new refresh token, and
  replace the old refresh token in the db with the new one.
- If client wants to log out of all devices, they can simply revoke all
  of their refresh tokens and they will be logged out when all their
  tokens expire (15 minute JWT tokens).

The advantages I see to this implementation are:

- No need to send two tokens. The refresh is embedded inside the JWT
  and cannot be modified because that would invalidate the signature.
- No need to encrypt the refresh token in the database because if an
  attacker got a hold of the refresh token, they cannot do anything
  with it because it is inside the JWT and cannot be modified. (In
  other implementations with separate tokens we should assume an
  attacker gets a hold of both anyways)

The problems I see with this are:

- JWTs always contain the refresh token, so the attacker will ALWAYS be
  able to perform a refresh and use the refresh token until it expires,
  unless the client revokes it by logging out (of all devices).
- The client can run the login call in a loop and fill up the database
  because every time they log in, a new access token is created and a
  new refresh token is stored into the database.

Is this method secure? If so, I'm primarily concerned with someone filling up the database with new refresh tokens and filling up the disk. How do I avoid that from happening?